# Displaying jQuery checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

This web page is currently displaying data from an "all" category from an rss feed once the page is loaded. My question is there are several categories which I would like the user to select and display. There are a total of 10 categories, and each correspond to a separate rss feed. Can anyone explain how I handle this event? Also, if one of the categories is selected, will it automatically override the current data being displayed? I will elaborate any unclear parts if needed. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/example',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function (xml) {
                $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
                    var title = $(this).find("title").text();
                    var description = $(this).find("description").text();
                    var linkUrl = $(this).find("link").text();
                    //var link = "<a href='" + linkUrl + "' target='_blank'>Read More<a>";
                      var displaytitle = "<a href='" + linkUrl + "' target='_blank'>" + title + "</a>"  
                    $('#feedContainer').append('<h3>'+displaytitle+'</h3><p>'+description+'</p>');

                });
            }
        });
});
</script>

</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
<!-- /field panel -->
    <div data-role="panel" id="fieldpanel" data-position="left" data-display="push">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
           <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Categories</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-bio" id="checkbox-bio">
        <label for="checkbox-bio">Bioengineering</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-com" id="checkbox-com">
        <label for="checkbox-com">Communications</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-eleP" id="checkbox-eleP">
        <label for="checkbox-eleP">Electrical/Power</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-eleD" id="checkbox-eleD">
        <label for="checkbox-eleD">Electronics/Design</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-nano" id="checkbox-nano">
        <label for="checkbox-nano">NanoEngineering</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-opt" id="checkbox-opt">
        <label for="checkbox-opt">Optics/Display</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-semi" id="checkbox-semi">
        <label for="checkbox-semi">Semiconductors</label>
    </fieldset>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /field panel -->

      <!-- /settings panel -->
     <div data-role="panel" id="settingspanel" data-position="right" data-display="push">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
          <li><a href="http://">Join IEEE</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://"> subscription services</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div><!-- /settings panel -->


    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <a href="#fieldpanel" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">Menu</a>
    <a href="#settingspanel" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">Settings</a>

    <h1>MOBILE</h1>

</div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div id="feedContainer"></div>  
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Advertisements</h4>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you want to get the basic information about this code!

Ok, the first thing to handle is the type of the data to be shown.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" />
```

Lets start with 2 instead of 10! The jQuery code for this would be easy to understand.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () { // click on checkbox
   var val = $(this).attr('id'); // get its id as value
   if(val == '2') {
      $('someelement).html('2 was selected');
      $('#1').prop('checked', false); // unselect the other one
   }
}
```

So, this is the basic code which will execute when a click event occurs on a checkbox. Now in your code you'll be using something like ajax then add the ajax request code before the `.html()` thing and write the response there.

To update the content being displayed you will be needed to use only one element as the basic clipboard for your app. Why? Because everytime you will get the data, you will be needed to replace the current content with that one and this way you will get only the current data; the selected data.

Lets try one checkbox from your code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-bio" id="checkbox-bio">
<label for="checkbox-bio">Bioengineering</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-com" id="checkbox-com">
<label for="checkbox-com">Communications</label>
```

Now lets handle the jQuery

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
  // and all others will be here just as they are.. to check the id
  // your ajax request is perfect, just copy paste that here..:)
});
```

But just need to make a change there, instead of sending the same request try to add one more thing there,

```
$.ajax({ 
  // url and datatype here,
  data: value
  // success function goes here
});
```

Note that the value was the variable that we took from the checkbox. Which will be sent with the request so that you can process only the necessary part of the RSS and leave all other, just like an `if else` block.

Here is a working fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/KU9JT/.

But I am sorry, I didnot include the if else block to make the code work as it was meant to be. But you'll understand how to manipulate this.

Comment: I am currently reading this over and wanted to thank you for your thorough response! I will let you know how things are coming along shortly. Cheers!

Comment: So I am still trying to piece everything together but I am unsure as to this part: $.ajax({ 
  // url and datatype here,
  data: value
  // success function goes here
});

Comment: Can you explain this part a bit more for me?$.ajax({ 
  // url and datatype here,
  data: value
  // success function goes here
});

Comment: That part is the ajax request for the data. But before success you will add data, the data is the string that is sent alongwith the request such as a query string, i.e. ?data=value .. this way!

Comment: Ok I'm following. I send you a message on google+, would you mind if I messaged what I have so far?

Comment: Well its 12:33AM and I am gonna sleep, would you mind waiting for some moments? However, yes you can post the code so that I can view and edit it for you :)